# how to split the date period in sql?

Tags: sql

Info:

```
   Date 1 nov 2016 to 5 nov 2016 = 10 members;
```

then people joined

```
   Date 3 nov 2016 to 7 Nov 2016 =12 members.
```

Now I want the data for  date 1 nov 2016  to 10 nov 2016.

Output will be

```
     From date  To date     No.of members
     1 nov 2016 2 nov 2016  10
     3 nov 2016 5 nov 2016  22
     6 nov 2016 7 nov 2016  12
```

Kindly Give me the suggestion to make query for that

Comment: Edit your question and (1) show what the data structure looks like as a table in the question; (2) tag with the database you want.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you would do this with a conditional sum:

```
with dates as (
      select startdate as dte, cnt
      from t
      union all
      select startdate + interval '1 day', - cnt
      from t
     )
select dte, sum(sum(cnt)) over (order by dte)
from dates
group by dte
order by dte;
```